# How to make field read only from page layout for particualr User

Tags: read-only

I've one object obj1 and field on that object field1 and one profile Billing User.

one Custom Button on obj1. when click on button. it will check the field1  to true for all the profile.

But i want field1 such that it should read only from page layout but it edit from apex, only for Billing User Profile.

how can i do?

Comment: only for one user or for particular profile?

Comment: @Ratan. for Particular Profile

Comment: why don't you just create a different pagelaout and make the field read only from pagelayout and assign to that profile ..

Comment: @Ratan. So as per your ans. I've 12 Record Type on this Obj. Thus i need to create 12 different Page layout for that Profile and make field read only from page layout  and assign to That Profile. Is It Correct?

Comment: ohh 12 layout.. this is little bit hard job I guess... not good idea.. if you have created 12 recordTypes then I guess you already created pagelayout for them isn't it?

Comment: Yes i've already Page Layout for Record Type

Comment: then just modify the pagelayout and make it read only

Comment: if we do like this then, this read only will apply to other Profile also because This page layout assign to other Profile also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42647/discussion-between-ratan-and-amol).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the field as Read Only on page layout.

[image]

Comment: The page Layout assign to Multiple Profile, if we use like this  then field we be read only for all profile but i want field editable for all profile except one profile

Answer (score 0):

From the "Quick find" box on the left search for "Field Accessibility" then choose your "obj1".
Select "View by fields" and choose "field1".
For each profile select "Read Only" besides for "Billing User".

Comment: yes it will be read only but it read only for apex class also and this field will not update through apex class.  I want this field update by apex class and not manually only for that Profile

Comment: How about go to profile, select your "Billing User", and under "Enabled Apex Class Access" add the apex class you want to give edit permission to. I have not tried it, but this might work.