# Custom Text field is not editable in Edit layout

Tags: related-list, product, order, locking, search-layout

I have added a custom field to the edit layout of the Order Product object, which appears after I click on Add Products button on the Order record page, in the Order products-related list. But I am not sure why, that field is showing as locked in the page layout popup, and is not editable.

I checked the field accessibility settings and it is editable there for my profile. And I even checked the field level security and confirmed that it is not marked as read-only.

I am adding the image of the same below, can someone please let me know why this field is showing as locked and is not editable in the edit layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is using Page Layouts, you can explicitly set a field as read only on a page layout as explained in [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131844/how-to-make-field-read-only-from-page-layout-for-particualr-user).

Alternatively if you are using dynamic forms, again you can control editability on the form itself as covered [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_req_fields.htm&type=5):

> If you set a field on a Lightning page to Required or Read-Only in the Lightning App Builder property panel, the behavior applies only to the field on that page, not all instances of the field.

In addition, it may be that there's an override for the "Edit" button in use. Use the "Setup > Object Manager" to find the required object, open it and navigate to "Buttons, Links, and Actions" to see if the Edit button has been overridden to use a custom page, for example.

Comment: Hey Phil, thank you for the answer. My problem is even though this field has edit access in both field-level security and accessibility. Even though it is editable in the record page layout. It is showing as locked in the edit layout and is not letting me edit it. And I am not how to unlock it and make it editable.

Comment: @AkshayVasu updated the answer to discuss overriding of the "Edit" button.

Comment: I just checked and confirmed that it hasn't been Overridden.